# How can i get and then send the id from the differents tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Im creating a website like a forum and i printing all posts from the database using PHP.

This is my code HTML where data-id gets a value(an id) from PHP.Each post has a code like this. As you can see, it has an event,so when i do clic on it(the a tag), it has to send that value using Ajax and make a request to bring back comments from the database and display the comments on a modal. I just can bring back comments from the first post. The other comments from the others post are not being displayed on the modal.

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewcomments()" class="comentarPosts"  data-id= <?php echo $posts_filas["Id_post"]; ?>    ><img src="img/message1.png"><span>25</span></a>
```

This is my ajax code:

```
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     document.querySelector(".comentarPosts").addEventListener("click", () => {
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "comentarios.php"); // No utilices el tercer parámetro, está deprecado
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status <= 299 && xhr.status >= 200) {
            document.getElementById("modal-message").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } else {
            alert("Error al conectar con la API");
        }
   }
   };
    const comentarPost = document.querySelector(".comentarPosts");
    xhr.send(`idPost=${comentarPost.getAttribute("data-id")}`);
  });
  });
```

I posted this question and it was closed.

I got this little example and it works:

```
     <html>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="b" class="comentarPosts"  data-id="1">25</a>
     </html>
     <script language="javascript">
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     document.querySelector(".comentarPosts").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    alert(event.srcElement.dataset.id);
   });
  });
```

But when i have more links like this below only work for the first one,but for the others links dont work:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="comentarPosts"  data-id="2">24</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="comentarPosts"  data-id="3">27</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="comentarPosts"  data-id="4">28</a>
  

   <script language="javascript">
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   document.querySelector(".comentarPosts").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    alert(event.srcElement.dataset.id);
  });
 });
```

That's the problem i want to resolve,clic on each links,taking the value from the data-id atributte and sending that value with ajax to make requests to the server.

Comment: The querySelector() method only returns the first element that matches the specified selectors.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      var x=document.querySelectorAll(".comentarPosts");
      for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
         x[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         var formdata = new FormData();
         formdata.append('idPost',event.srcElement.dataset.id);
         xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "comentarios.php", true);
        xhttp.send(formdata);
        });
      });
```

Comment: @How i include this to my ajax code? Sorry man,i'm very short in JS.

Comment: you can send like this

Comment: I will change to JQuery.Sorry